# Resolve accessbility issues in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

How to create tables using iText which are as per accessibility guidelines?

I have certain tables created using iText 5 in c# and I have the following accessibility issues to address in them.

```
TR must be a child of Table, THead, TBody, or TFoot
```

The code that I am using:

```
table.writeSelectedRows(0,-1,omit,omit,writer.directContent);
```

When I do this it generates a tr tag and not a a table.
I have already tried the solution below but no luck.

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
canvas.beginMarkedContentSequence(PdfName.ARTIFACT);
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 30, canvas);
canvas.endMarkedContentSequence();
```

Comment: iText 5.5.x can easily create accessible documents if you allow iText to create the layout (that is: if you use `document.add(table);`) but you decided to take care of the layout yourself (you write to the `PdfContentByte`). That makes it extremely difficult to introduce accessibility. Actually: we decided that it was so difficult that we decided to rewrite iText from scratch with iText 7 as result. So the real question is: why are you using iText 5 instead of iText 7?

Comment: The architecture of iText 5 dates from 2000. PDF/UA (the accessibility standard) dates from 2012. When the iText 5 architecture was created (by me), I had no idea that I would ever have to support accessibiliy (nor Tagged PDF for that matter) and when the need arose, accessibilty was bolted onto the old architecture. That worked, but we regretted some architectural choices made in the past. We hesitated to rewrite iText from scratch because it was a huge investment, but in the end we decided that it was needed, so we spent a lot of time and money on that project.

Comment: These are things you should consider when using iText. If you are not paying for your use of iText, know that a lot of money went into building a better product. Please don't complain saying "but I already spent a lot of time on iText 5!" We have spent more time and money on iText 7. Also be aware that both iText 5 and iText 7 are licensed as AGPL software, which means that there are some restrictions. If you intend to use iText in a closed source project, you'll have to purchase a commercial license. That is how we fund our development. I hope you understand.